# find minimum value in list of strings and numbers python

Tags: python, path

I have the ouput

```
[['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'd', 20.0], ['a', 'b', 'd', 11.0], ['a', 'c', 'd', 10.0]]
```

and I want to grab the minimum path which in this case would be 10

it's a path finding algorithm and the letters can vary

i tried using a key of float but couldn't figure it out

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `key` argument to `min()`:

```
path = min(my_list, key=operator.itemgetter(-1))
```

This will apply the key function to each element of the list, and return the element for which the result of applying that funciton is minimal.  The function `operator.itemgetter(-1)` returns the last element of each list.

That said, you might reconsider your data structure.  The hybride lists that contain names and then a floating point number as last element seem cumbersome to work with.  Using a list of tuples with two entries might make your code more natural, in spite of adding one nesting level:

```
[(['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'd'], 20.0),
 (['a', 'b', 'd'], 11.0),
 (['a', 'c', 'd'], 10.0)]
```

Comment: or even `SomeArray = collections.namedtuple('SomeArray', ['letters','path'])` and `min([SomeArray(['a','b','a','c','d'], 20.0), SomeArray(['a','b','d'], 11.0), ... ], key=operator.attrgetter('path'))` But then I again I love namedtuples :)

Comment: when I use that it gives me 
    TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list

Comment: @MichaelAlexanderHarris: What do you mean by "tha"?  The way of determining the minimum, or the data structure?  If you change the data structure, you of course need to adapt the code.

Comment: the path = min(my_list, key=operator.itemgetter(-1))

I haven't changed the data structure

I did return path and it gave me the type error, but before that it gave 
ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence

Comment: @MichaelAlexanderHarris: Not sure what you are trying to do -- the code works for me: http://ideone.com/TMrwRP